# Checking for null value (not nil or NSnull) in swift always return nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, string, sqlite

I am working on a project which uses both swift an objective c. The team member before me have written this code in objective C ,which I am not familiar with. There is problem that most of the part involving storing and retrieving value from Sqlite is in obj C. This has been done in a common class to avoid Code redemption. However if i use swift to retrieve value through that obj C file a problem occur. If there is no value in that specified row it return "null".[image]

Update: Checked for optional binding as said by Antony Raphel
[image: Same error persists.]

Even if i check for nil directly before converting to 'as? String' the same error persist. I came to know that there is no equivalent of "null" in swift. Is there any hack to the value is empty (null) in swift?

Comment: you can directly check that "Your string" == " "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your

```
var prevNotifCount = self.cmmn.getPreviousNotificationCount() as? String
```

and use

```
  guard let prevNotifCount = self.cmmn.getPreviousNotificationCount()      else{
              print("No previous notification value") 
              return 
        }
```

no need to check for nil, if it will fail , else block will be executed

Comment: This solved my issue. conversion to as? String always return null .. I have edited your post to the code that solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

```
if let prevNotifCount = self.cmmn.getPreviousNotificationCount() as? String
{
   self.cmmn.saveInDatabase("19", phoneNumber: "0", otp: "0")
   print(self.cmmn.getPreviousNotificationCount())
} 
else
{
    print("No previous notification value")
}
```

This is standard Swift approach called `optional binding`. You safely unwrap an optional and if it is not nil assign it to a local variable

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding if let to check nil condition like this:-

```
if let NotifCount = self.cmmn,getPreviousNotificationCount() as? String

{
    prevNotifCount = NotifCount
}
```

Please try this, Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use if let statement.

```
if let preNotifCount = self.cmmn.getPreviousNotofication {
      //business logic
}
```

Now business logic would only be executed if preNotifCount is not nil.